# Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a Composable function

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have query that I need to call in `scope.launch`:

```
   composeView {
            MyTheme {
                // Create a CoroutineScope that follows this composable's lifecycle
                val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
                LaunchedEffect(key1 = "", block = {
                    composableScope.launch {
                        val b: Boolean = database.query()
                    }
                })
            }
```

Now I want to pass `b` to a `Composble` :

```
@Composable
    private fun Content(b: Boolean) {

    }
```

How should I call Content since `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`? If I put Content inside launch block, I receive above error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the scopes to make the background calls like fetching from the database and make use of mutable states to pass it on to a composable.

For Example:

```
val foo = remember { mutableStateOf("") } 

LaunchedEffect(true) { 
  foo.value = bar()
}

Text (text = foo.value)
```